# List within a List within a Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, syntax

I have a apparent syntax issue and I just can't seem to figure out why. It's probably a simple solution, of course. And I've already scoured Google for people with this problem, and no one had this specific question, and I couldn't extrapolate an answer from any of their answers...

Here's my code:

```
inventory = {
    'backpack' : ['Paper', 'Pencil', 'Bread loaf']
    'apparel' : ['head' : [], 'neck' : ['Special Necklace'], 'torso' : ['Old T-shirt'], 'legs' : ['Old jeans'], 'feet' : ['Worn tennis shoes']]
    'belt' : ['Pocket knife']
}
```

It's just a crude inventory system for a little side-game I'm dabbling with. But the problem Python says is on the line with the 'apparel' list. The little ^ that is supposed to show exactly where the problem is doesn't move when I add or remove characters either. All Python says is that I have "Invalid Syntax"...

Why won't the list inside a list work?

Answer (score 1):

`Inventory['apparel']` looks like it should be a `dict`, not a list... e.g. `{'head' : [], ...}`, not `['head': []]` (as the latter is invalid syntax)

```
inventory = {
    'backpack' : ['Paper', 'Pencil', 'Bread loaf'],
    'apparel' : {'head' : [], 'neck' : ['Special Necklace'], 'torso' : ['Old T-shirt'], 'legs' : ['Old jeans'], 'feet' : ['Worn tennis shoes']},
    'belt' : ['Pocket knife']
}
```

You're also missing a comma after the `'backpack'` and `apparel` lists.

Comment: Oh, and belated congrats on hitting the big 6 digits!

Comment: @mgilson Congratulations man... :-) Its been a long time since I seen you in chat.

Comment: Sweet, thanks. Like I said- simple error... Plus I'm kinda new to Python, I'm using Codecademy to learn haha

Comment: @Willman42 `'key': ['value1', 'value2'],` <- each pair has to be separate by a comma.

Comment: @Willman42 -- Sure, no problem.  Everybody has to start somewhere.  Keep working and you'll be a pro in no time :-)

Comment: @thefourtheye -- Thanks.  Unfortunately, Google keeps me too busy to do more than answer a couple questions per day.  If you look at my reputation history, there's a sharp decline in my rep gaining rate that starts right around July 2013 :-).